# Error when converting a time to sun time using the overlap package

Tags: r, date, time

I continually get this error when trying to convert to sun time. I am using two separate columns with date and time (in radians) to calculate sun time following the exact code from the overlap package. My times are from multiple time zones, thus i want to transform so I can compare them directly.

Error in year[corr] <- year[corr] - 1 :    NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments.

My code is below, I do not get the error until the last line using the function sunTime():

```
snap_car<-read.csv("snapshot_data_carnivores.csv")

##add column with time in radians
snapshot<-mutate(snap_car, times.rf=60 * 24 * as.numeric(times(snap_car$Time))/1440*2*pi)
str(snapshot)

##Convert dates to POSIX with right time zone
dates.rf <- as.POSIXct(strptime(snap_car$Date, "%Y-%m-%d"), tz = "US/Central")
View(dates.rf)

##Create a SpatialPoints object with the location
coords <- matrix(c(-90, 30), nrow=1)
Coords <- sp::SpatialPoints(coords,proj4string=sp::CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
View(Coords)

st<-sunTime(snapshot$times.rf, dates.rf, Coords)
```

Comment: Is this R code? Please tag it with "r" so people do not have to guess.

Comment: At first glance it seems like you have some Not Available values in the data you are passing to sunTime. Why?

Comment: @DavidK I have looked through the dates.rf (YYYY/MM/DD) and times.rf (radial time) columns of my data and there are no NAs present. I have over 5000 rows each representing a given event. I also do not understand what the first part of the error is telling me.

Comment: Maybe there's an error in sunTime. I don't know that function; can you get access to the source? Maybe do some debugging of your own? Is there someone you can file a bug report with? Maybe try deleting half the rows of input to see if the problem occurs in the first half or only the second half, then delete half the remaining rows, etc, until you find a minimal set of rows that cause the problem--maybe just one row. That might give some clues.

Comment: Thanks DavidK! I did get this to work by running sections of my data set and finding an extra space in one date cell that was throwing off my entire code.

Comment: I'm very glad to know I had at least one idea that helped!